# sort usage question

Tags: sort

I have a file junk like this:

```
Y10 122.894054 7.653405
B3 124.406526 8.281803
B3' 125.000684 8.389677
A11 102.801917 9.288624
A11' 127.661564 8.216719
D4 117.182791 7.418388
```

and I want to sort the first column by the number, like this:

```
B3 124.406526 8.281803
B3' 125.000684 8.389677
D4 117.182791 7.418388
Y10 122.894054 7.653405
A11 102.801917 9.288624
A11' 127.661564 8.216719
```

I use this command but is not working for me:

```
sort -k1,23 -k1n junk
```

Comment: @don_crissti, you may as well add that as an answer.  I think it is *the* answer, and it's helpful to others as well as the Original Poster.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily adding a (hopefully) unique separator (e.g. '#') before the first number:

```
sed 's/^\([^0-9]*\)/\1#/' junk | sort -t '#' -k 2n,2 | tr -d '#'
```

This is the general case where I sort for the first number in any text file which does not contain '#' before the first number.

You could also use a more exotic separator if your sort likes it:

```
SEP=`printf '\02'`
sed "s/^\([^0-9]*\)/\1$SEP/" junk | sort -t "$SEP" -k 2n,2 | tr -d "$SEP"
```

Comment: +1, on my system I get `sort: multi-character tab ‘§’` with this seperator, but replacing `'§'` with a different character works.

Comment: I think # is more seldom used in csv files than space that's why I preferred #. \x02 is good but  maybe more difficult to type portable!? I'll add this.

Comment: it works for me and does the job for what i need. perfect